# Flutter Injectable: inject multiple instances of generic types via annotation

Tags: flutter, generics, dependency-injection, injectable

I am using get_it in my flutter project for the dependency injection.
Now I am trying to do it with injectable to replace my handwritten dependency file with annotations.

I have the special case, that I have a class which is generic and must be injected 3 times with a different value of T.

```
class TestBloc<T> {
    ...
}
```

This is how it looks like in my old config:

```
sl.registerFactory(() => TestBloc<One>(...);
sl.registerFactory(() => TestBloc<Two>(...);
sl.registerFactory(() => TestBloc<Three>(...);
```

How can I annotate the class to make that work?

When I add @injectable

```
@injectable
class TestBloc<T> {
    ...
}
```

I get this (of course):

```
gh.factory<_i34.TestBloc<dynamic>>(() =>_i34.TestBloc<dynamic>(...);
```

**How to annotate to get this?**

```
gh.factory<_i34.TestBloc<One>>(() =>_i34.TestBloc<One>(...);
gh.factory<_i34.TestBloc<Two>>(() =>_i34.TestBloc<Two>(...);
gh.factory<_i34.TestBloc<Three>>(() =>_i34.TestBloc<Three>(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution I came up with does the job. You have to create a factory for your view model with generic type. Inside you can ask for all of the dependencies of generic type that you need. Then unfortunately you have to construct all your dependencies manually. But essentially it is the same as binding. Next you have to extend the factory for your specific type. This will make sure all the required types are filled in. Then the compiler can search for these types. The beauty is that for each variant of your type you can override some bindings. And if you really want you can also provide a different implementation of factory.
Small example:

```
abstract class StdOutUseCase<T> {
  void printEmpty();
}

mixin Arbitrary<T> {
  T call(Random random);
}

mixin Empty<T> {
  T call();
}

class MockViewModel<T> {
  final StdOutUseCase<T> stdOutUseCase;

  MockViewModel(this.stdOutUseCase);

  void onButtonClick() {
    stdOutUseCase.printEmpty();
  }
}

@Injectable(as: Empty<String>)
class StringEmpty with Empty<String> {
  @override
  String call() {
    return "";
  }
}

@Injectable(as: Arbitrary<String>)
class ArbString with Arbitrary<String> {
  static const adjectives = ["happy", "smart", "cool", "cold"];
  static const nouns = ["fox", "bear", "gorilla"];

  @override
  String call(Random random) {
    return "${adjectives[random.nextInt(adjectives.length)]} ${nouns[random.nextInt(nouns.length)]}";
  }
}

@Injectable(as: Factory<MockViewModel<String>>)
class StringFactory extends MockVMFactory<String> {
  StringFactory(super.empty, super.arbitrary);
}

mixin Factory<T>{
  T call();
}


class MockVMFactory<T> with Factory<MockViewModel<T>> {
  final Empty<T> empty;
  final Arbitrary<T> arbitrary;

  MockVMFactory(this.empty, this.arbitrary);

  @override
  MockViewModel<T> call() => MockViewModel(useCase());

  StdOutUseCase<T> useCase() => FancyStdOutUseCase(empty, arbitrary);
}

class FancyStdOutUseCase<T> extends StdOutUseCase<T> {
  final Empty<T> empty;
  final Arbitrary<T> arbitrary;

  FancyStdOutUseCase(this.empty, this.arbitrary);

  @override
  void printEmpty() {
    print("Empty is ${empty()} and random is ${arbitrary(Random())}");
  }
}

class BaseStdOutUseCase<T> extends StdOutUseCase<T> {
  final Empty<T> empty;

  @inject
  BaseStdOutUseCase(this.empty);

  @override
  void printEmpty() {
    print("Empty for $T is ${empty()}");
  }
}
```